# Removing records from a stored procedure recordset

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, code-behind

I have a stored procedure that returns a recordset (resultset A) based on a complex query, and the records are in a particular sequence. I have another query that returns ID values from another table (resultset B).

I want to do something like "Get me records from resultset A where id exists in (resultset B)".

I need to do this in codebehind. Any ideas how to go about doing this?

Comment: can you be very specific in your terminology? "recordset" is (unless you are using legacy ADO) ambiguous; how is your data currently stored? is it in two `DataTable` insteances? in two `List<T>` (probably for different `T`)? or...?

Comment: Most likely this kind of filtering can be done in TSQL by writing complex queries. If you are not very efficient with complex queries, it will be best to share query so that, some expert fix the query instead finding workarounds. Try to fix it at initial stage instead in later steps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this extension method - based on yield and `Linq Contains operator`

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Select(this DataReader reader, int index)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        yield return reader[index].ToString();
    }
}
```

Nota : you have two recordset reader1 and reader2, Select extension method get list of item IEnumerable.

```
var list1 = reader1.Select(0); //Search on first column;
var list2 = reader2.Select(0);
//Get list items of values (index 0) of list2, who exist in list1.
var result = from item on list2.Select(0)
             where list1.Contains(item)
             select item;
```